# Serving Static Files google app Engine, Ajax failed

Tags: ajax, google-app-engine

I am new to GAE and I cannot figure this out so please your help, I have the following folder tree in my application:
`static
--images
---subImages
--index.html`

I am getting the content of subImages folder with Ajax like this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: folder,
        success: function (data) {
            $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
                if (val.match(/\.jpg|\.png|\.gif/)) {
                    $("#gallery").append("<img src='" + folder + val + "'" + " data-image='" + folder + val + "'" + ">");
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

I am getting 404 Error
my YAML file from here: https://gist.github.com/darktable/873098

Comment: Run the app locally - you'll be able to see the actual request coming in and determine if the problem is in ajax building the request or really missing data on GAE side. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-local-server

Comment: thanks for the comment, actually I can access the `subImages` folder contents, but the ajax request is failing, maybe GAE not allowing the folder to be browsed or something like that?

Comment: What do the app logs say?

Answer (score 0):

The `app.yaml` and information that you link to is really out of date. It loads the `runtime: python`, which is Python 2.5 and has been deprecated. Its got other issues too.

You probably should follow along with the official tutorial on [Hosting a static website on App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/hosting-a-static-website). You'd likely end up with an `app.yaml` like the following:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
# no application or version elements now that we prefer
# the Cloud SDK and gcloud deployments as those are command
# line parameters now.

handlers:
- url: /static/(.*)
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*)

- url: /
  static_files: index.html
  upload: index.html

# If you wanted a wildcard match for other static files that
# in the example case are in a `www` folder.
#- url: /(.*)
#  static_files: www/\1
#  upload: www/(.*)
```